# python code understanding

Tags: python

I have following code

```
def compare_and_swap(x, a, b):
    if x[a] > x[b]:
        x[a], x[b] = x[b], x[a]

def oddeven_merge(x, lo, hi, r):
    step = r * 2
    if step < hi - lo:
        oddeven_merge(x, lo, hi, step)
        oddeven_merge(x, lo + r, hi, step)
        for i in range(lo + r, hi - r, step):
            compare_and_swap(x, i, i + r)
    else:
        compare_and_swap(x, lo, lo + r)

def oddeven_merge_sort_range(x, lo, hi):
    """ sort the part of x with indices between lo and hi.

    Note: endpoints (lo and hi) are included.
    """
    if (hi - lo) >= 1:
        # if there is more than one element, split the input
        # down the middle and first sort the first and second
        # half, followed by merging them.
        mid = lo + ((hi - lo) / 2)
        oddeven_merge_sort_range(x, lo, mid)
        oddeven_merge_sort_range(x, mid + 1, hi)
        oddeven_merge(x, lo, hi, 1)

def oddeven_merge_sort(x):
    oddeven_merge_sort_range(x, 0, len(x)-1)

>>> data = [4, 3, 5, 6, 1, 7, 8]
>>> oddeven_merge_sort(data)
>>> data
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Everything is clear for me ,but  only this line can't understand well

```
 for i in range(lo + r, hi - r, step):
```

How can I read it using pseudo code?or in other languages for instance C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This equivalent to

```
for(int i=lo+r;i<(hi-r);i+=step)
```

in C (or C++, Java, C#, etc.)

(Note: this will only work if `step` is positive. If step is negative - i.e. lo+r>hi-r, you need change the check to `i>(hi-r)`)

What it does is start a counter at `lo+r`, move it by `step` units until the counter equals or steps past `hi-r`.

Comment: What you have is very dangerous, could loop forever. I don't believe it's equivalent to the python range.

Comment: @Mat: True. It may loop forever, but I can't think of a way that works for both positive and negative `step` in C-like languages. I am updating my answer to work only for the positive case.

Comment: @MAK, you fixed your code but not the description in the final paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Line

```
for i in range(lo + r, hi - r, step):
```

is a *for loop* with i running from `lo+r` to `hi-r` *not included*, by steps of `step`.  Here is an example:

```
>>> for i in range(10, 31, 3):
...     print i
...     
10
13
16
19
22
25
28
```

Note that in `range(start, end, step)`, **the start and end values can be ordered in any way** and that **step can be positive or negative**.  This makes writing a C version a little cumbersome.

Thus, once you know **Python**, `for i in range(lo + r, hi - r, step` **is the pseudo-code**: in fact,

- it is arguably more concise and legible than a while loop  with counter initialization, test and increment on three different lines;
- it nicely handles all the cases covered by Python (ordering of the start and end, and sign of the step).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I read it using pseudo code?

Python is very close to being pseudocode.

```
for i in range(lo + r, hi - r, step):
```

means exactly what it says: do the following code with each value of `i` in the specified `range`. The first two values are the lower and upper bounds of the range, and the `step` is the distance between values to use. For more information, try `help(range)` at the Python interpreter prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Its a loop from `lo + r` (inclusive) to `hi -r` (exclusive) in increments of `step`.

Assuming step is positive, in C-like languages it could be written as:

```
 for (i = lo + r; i < hi - r; i += step) { ... }
```

Another way to write it in Python:

```
 i = lo + r
 while i < hi - r:
      # loop body
      i += step
```

If step is negative, the `<` becomes `>` in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can read that as the following pseudo-code (for positive steps):

```
i = lo + r
while i < hi - r:
    # body of loop
    i = i + step
```

For negative steps:

```
i = lo + r
while i > hi - r:
    # body of loop
    i = i + step
```

In other words, it iterates the `i` variable from the first value, until it reaches or passes the second value, adjusting it by the third value each time through the loop.